# Patent conflict for artificial beehive

Tags: prior-art, us20140370781

There is a patent pending application for an artificial beehive ([US 2014/0370781 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140370781)).

However, there is a very similar patent from 1939 ([US 2,223,561 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US2223561)).

Is the newer application patentable?

Comment: There has already been a third party submission for US 2,223,561 A as prior art (February 20, 2015). Source: [USPTO Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). It has been added to the case file and will be available to the examiner.